# Unreadable Notebook: FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have 3 anaconda environments and install different modules of Python in them. I can open and run Jupiter notebook with no problem in all of them.

Now when I create the new Anaconda environment with following commands :

```
conda  create -n tf tensorflow
conda activate tf
```

After that I issue  followings:

```
pip install keras
pip install pandas
pip install jupyterlab
```

or even

```
pip install notebook
```

Then when I open the notebooks that I can open and run easily in other environments including the base. I received the following error:

> Unreadable Notebook:FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')

I am using Python 3.7 and OS is Windows 10. I have removed and created the new environment multiple times still I have the same problem.

I would appreciate if anyone can help me solve this problem.

Comment: I have this same problem, on Mac.  I have tried the two solutions mentioned here, and neither is relevant -- the file has the proper extension, and I reinstalled jupyter into a fresh environment using conda navigator instead of conda from the command line: same error.  Can't open any notebooks -- just get `FileNotFoundError` from pathnames that are valid (and can be tested with `ls` by pasting to the command line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same problem, I fixed by, instead of using terminal I used anaconda navigator to install Jupyter Notebook. That fixed my problem, hope it helps. I think it was because I used pip to install jupyter rather than conda.

Comment: Installing Jupyter using conda install jupyter did the trick.

Answer (score -1):

**Check the notebook file extension**: While saving, file type extension gets appended at the end of the actual file name such as **notebook.ipynb** could be **notebook.ipynb.txt** You can check this by disabling the *Hide file extension* from folder settings.